# confusing s3 bucket policy upload issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want my app to be able to put objects into an s3 bucket, and i want the public to be able to read the objects. For some reason uploads are not working unless I have block all public access turned off. Logs show this error: `Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied`

My Block public access settings look like so:
[image]

And my Bucket policy looks like so:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "GetPhoto",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::site-public/photo/*"
        }
    ]
```

The public access settings say they *do not* block bucket policies, but the functionality is still being blocked. Why?

Comment: What function is being blocked (what is your client actually doing?) and what is the error code/message?

Comment: If you are trying to upload objects with public ACLs it will be blocked unless you turn off all the options. [Blocking public access S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html#configuring-block-public-access). <Public access is granted to buckets and objects through access control lists (ACLs), policies, bucket policies, or all. To help ensure that all of your Amazon S3 access points, buckets, and objects have their public access blocked, we recommend that you turn on all four settings for block public access for your accoun>

Comment: @jarmod client is uploading image and the error is `Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied`. @samtoddler i keep getting confused on this issue. i have `acl: "public-read"` in my upload options. shouldn't i have SOME access blocked? i don't want everyone to be able to upload, but i do want everyone to be able to get files. how can i upload these files without exposing the entire bucket?

Comment: If you want to be able to [selectively make objects public](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/) with a public-read ACL then you'll need to disable the BPA settings related to ACLs.

Comment: @jarmod thank you! that def solved the upload problem, but now when i view the files, i see this: `<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>324DA73F23EE2118</RequestId>
<HostId>FN9N3x7pIoNLPgnWqhfsIb1e3Slbrn2b05wH3HObrc7DIj+51JMSSk8VxH+6YSb3lK2wuF8eIqc=</HostId>
</Error>`

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve the files and are they definitely under `s3://site-public/photo/`?

Comment: @jarmod btw if you want to write up the answer (disable BPA settings) then i could mark you as the winner. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to be able to selectively make objects publicly readable with the public-read ACL so you will need to disable the Block Public Access setting related to ACLs.